# (Ubuntu 14.04) apt-get libopencv-dev, but get errors: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, apt-get

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-dev : Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-videostab-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-superres-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-ocl-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcv-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libhighgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcvaux-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

also, I used "aptitude install libopencv-dev", but it did not work. So I don't know how to finished this problem.

Comment: those libs look pretty much outdated, too (cv,cvaux are opencv1.0 things, not 2.4.x) .better get src from github (2.4.11) and compile that.

Answer (score 9):

The packages in the official repos are outdated, don't use them. This is what I use to install OpenCV, should work for you too.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential make cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config python python-dev python-numpy libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/itseez/opencv
mv opencv /opt
cd /opt/opencv
git checkout 2.4.10.1 #or whatever version you want
sudo mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake -j4 -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
sudo make -j4
sudo make -j4 install
sudo ldconfig
```

Refer to this http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

Answer (score 1):

I needed the OpenCV 3.2 and with the needs of enabling hardware acceleration modules and i followed this procedure on ubuntu 14.04.5:

1. download the required libraries:

```sh
sudo apt-get install
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  git \
  libgtk2.0-dev \
  pkg-config \
  libavcodec-dev \
  libavformat-dev \
  libswscale-dev \
  python-dev \
  python-numpy \
  libtbb2 \
  libtbb-dev \
  libjpeg-dev \
  libpng-dev \
  libtiff-dev \
  libjasper-dev \
  libdc1394-22-dev
```

2. [download opencv](http://opencv.org/downloads.html)
3. extract, cd in the directory and run:

```sh
mkdir build

cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=OFF -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D WITH_OPENCL=ON -D WITH_VA_INTEL=ON -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON ..

make -j8 #to run 8 different jobs in parallel

sudo make install

add the line "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" to the .bashrc file

sudo ldconfig
```

Hope it can help