# How to install opencv on Ubuntu14.04?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu-14.04

When I want to install opencv on Ubuntu14.04, I get problem as bellow:libopencv-dev : Depends: libopencv-objdetect-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-legacy-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-contrib-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-videostab-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-superres-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libopencv-ocl-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcv-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libhighgui-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcvaux-dev (= 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Then I follow the answer of [(Ubuntu 14.04) apt-get libopencv-dev, but get errors: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454724/ubuntu-14-04-apt-get-libopencv-dev-but-get-errors-unable-to-correct-problems)

And I can not install libgtk2.0-dev. I get the problem of installing libgtk2.0-dev:The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-dev (>= 2.27.3) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-dev (>= 2.21.0) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libatk1.0-dev (>= 1.29.2) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libcairo2-dev (>= 1.6.4-6.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libxrandr-dev (>= 2:1.2.99) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Any suggestions? This is freaking me out! I have googled mant times. But there isn't a solution.Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to "apt-get update && apt-get upgrade" ??

If you have broken packages, you can use "apt-get install -f"

-f, --fix-broken
    Fix. Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place. This option, when used with install/remove, can omit any packages to permit APT to deduce a likely solution. Any package(s) that are specified must completely correct the problem. This option is sometimes necessary when running APT for the first time; APT itself does not allow broken package dependencies to exist on a system. It is possible that a system's dependency structure can be so corrupt as to require manual intervention. Use of this option together with -m may produce an error in some situations.

Comment: Thank you and I will have a try. I use sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude -y install libopencv-dev solved my problem.